# simple question regarding change of variable using Ei(x)

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

Given that $\int_2^x {1\over \log(t)} \, dt = Li(x)$

can be represented as,

$\text{Li(x)}=-\int_{\log(2)}^{\log(x)}\frac{e^{-y}}{y}=\text{Ei}(\log(x))-\text{Ei}(\log(2))$

where $\text{Ei(x)}=\int_{x}^{\infty}\frac{e^{-q}}{q}$ is the Expontential integral,

The simple question is how step by step does ${1\over \log(t)} \,$ become $\frac{e^{-y}}{y}$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks straightforward.  $y=-log(t),\ t=e^{-y},\ dt=-e^{-y}dy$.  Put it together to get the new expression for Li(x).